# Adding multiple namespace declarations in XmlWriter

Tags: namespaces, xmlwriter

I am trying to write out the following element using XmlWriter

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
```

I've got the very first declaration done using

```
writer.WriteStartElement("kml", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
```

How can I add the remaining 3 declarations to the same element?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","gx", null, "http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","kml", null, "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2");
writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns","atom", null, "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
```

Got that from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfche0ka(v=vs.100).aspx.

Answer (score 11):

The answer of [Ryan B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157114/ryan-b) is incomplete as the XML namespace is only written as attribute but not registered in the name table, so `LookupPrefix` will fail getting prefix of one of the XML namespaces, f.i. `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`. It will return `null` instead `atom`.

To write a namespace attribute and get namespace registered use

```
writer.WriteAttributeString("atom",
                            "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/",
                            "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
```

**Use of namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/`registers also the prefix in name table.**

Comment: It is worth noting the unstated bit here: including the URI for the xmlns namespace has the side-effect of writing "xmlns" to the attribute, thus the leading parameter seen in the earlier code is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

The namespaces are simply attributes.  Use the standards means of writing attributes for the element.